# Need help fixing a bug in a browser game

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a very simple browser memory game which you need to to flip all the matched cards in order to win.

**The bug :**

In the game if you click fast enough you can flip more than 2 cards.

I've tried a lot to fix it but couldn't figure it out by myself. I would appreciate any help in solving this issue as I am new to JavaScript and it's still hard for me fix those basic bugs.

Game files:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <button class="Change User" onclick="change(this)">Change User</button>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/layout/logo.png">
    <h1>Memory Monsters</h1>
    <p id="Play Again"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="1" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/1.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="7" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/7.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/5.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-card="5" onclick="cardClicked(this)">
    <img src="img/cards/5.png">
    <img class="back" src="img/cards/back.png">
  </div>

  <script src="js/game.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
var getElementsByClassName = prompt ('What is your name?');
window.localStorage.setItem ('name', 'dan');
function change(username) {
    prompt('What is your name?');
}

// Those are global variables, they stay alive and reflect the state of the game
var elPreviousCard = null;
var flippedCouplesCount = 0;

// This is a constant that we dont change during the game (we mark those with CAPITAL letters)
var TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT = 3;

// Load an audio file
var audioWin = new Audio('sound/win.mp3');

// This function is called whenever the user click a card
function cardClicked(elCard) {

    // If the user clicked an already flipped card - do nothing and return from the function
    if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) {
        return;
    }

    // Flip it
    elCard.classList.add('flipped');

    // This is a first card, only keep it in the global variable
    if (elPreviousCard === null) {
        elPreviousCard = elCard;
    } else {
        // get the data-card attribute's value from both cards
        var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute('data-card');
        var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');

        // No match, schedule to flip them back in 1 second
        if (card1 !== card2){
            setTimeout(function () {
                elCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard = null;
            }, 1000)

        } else {
            // Yes! a match!
            flippedCouplesCount++;
            elPreviousCard = null;

            // All cards flipped!
            if (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT === flippedCouplesCount) {
                audioWin.play();

                // and finally add a button to call resetCard() 
        document.getElementById("Play Again").innerHTML =
        '<button onclick="resetCard();">Play Again</button>';
            }

        }

    }

}

function resetCard() {// to erase the flipped classes
    var cardclass = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    for (i = 0; i < cardclass.length; i++) {
      cardclass[i].classList.remove("flipped");
      document.getElementById("Play Again").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid darkcyan;
    color:darkcyan;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

.header img {
    float:right;
}

.card {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;    
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;

}

.card img {
    position: absolute;
}

.flipped .back {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: `var getElementsByClassName = prompt ('What is your name?');` This is pretty suspcious

Comment: hmm what suspcious about it ? i was just playing with some javascript options. i don't think it has anything to do with what i asked.

Answer (score 0):

i made a game like this. you need to create a variable that starts on 0

`let tries = 0;`

then add one to it each time a card is selected. make sure to not allow it to count if a card that is already flipped is clicked again. here is some of the code from the function that is run on my onclick. I am using a React framework, but if you write this logic in your JS function, it is what you will need to make it work

```
selected = (event) => {

        if (canClick === true) {
            let id = event.currentTarget.id; //card0
            let idString = id.toString(); //"card0"

            //ONLY ALLOW A CARD TO BE CLICKED IF ITS FACE DOWN
            if (this.state[idString] === cardBack) {

                idString = idString.replace(/card/g, ''); //"0"
                this.setState({[id] : arrayRandom[idString]});

                //FIRST PICK
                if (counter % 2 == 1) {
                    curCard1 = arrayRandom[idString].toString();
                    id1 = id;
                    counter++;
                //SECOND PICK
                } else {
                    //MAKE SURE A CARD DOESN'T GET SELECTED TWICE IN A ROW AND STAY FACE UP
                    if (id === id1) {
                        console.log("Select a different card for your second pick");
                    } else {
                        counter++;
                        tries++;
                        canClick = false; //STOP USER FROM SELECTING ANOTHER CARD
                        curCard2 = arrayRandom[idString].toString();
                        id2 = id;
                        setTimeout(() => {canClick = true}, 1000); //USER CAN PICK AGAIN IN 1 SEONCD
                        //IF THERE'S A MATCH - CARDS STAY FLIPPED, SCORE INCREASES BY 1
                        if (curCard1 == curCard2) {
                            score = score + 1;
                        //IF THERE'S NO MATCH - CARDS FLIP FACE DOWN AFTER A SECOND
                        } else {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.setState({[id1]: cardBack});
                                this.setState({[id2]: cardBack});
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.log("This card has already been flipped, select another one");
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my game
https://reactcardmatch.netlify.com/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, is it possible that you can display this in my code? i have no idea where to place it

Comment: this is a method ( a function of a class ) to make it an arrow function in ES6 you would just need to define it by placing the `let` keyword in front of the function declaration like `let selected = (event) => {....}` you will have to pick thru this and customize your variables and might need to remove calls to `this.` and `state` as those wont be available unless you use the React component class. This is more of the type of answer that you could learn from by spending some time dissecting it. THE LOGIC for what you need is here, that is the key.